# Launch Console App from SharePoint Online

Tags: c#, sharepoint, console-application, office365

I have written a console application on Visual Studio (c#) that pulls data from an external website and updates my SharePoint Online website. The idea was to have this console application running every 3 hours which would pull data using webservices and update my SP Online site. However, the users are requesting this to run On Demand. I am trying to create a button or something on the SharePoint page that could possibly trigger this console exe file.

Could anyone help me with how I should be approaching this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have online a SPOnline aka O365 or do you have a VM in Azure etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a [remote timer job in SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt204004.aspx)

Timer jobs in SharePoint are used to perform background tasks to manage or govern your environment.
Remote timer jobs do not run on the SharePoint server (O365 in your case). Instead remote timer jobs are scheduled tasks that run on another server.